# JavaScript do while hangs and makes browser out of memory

Tags: javascript, jquery, timeout, do-while

I'm not sure if I'm doing something wrong, haven't really used do while in JS but I would like to check every 5 seconds if row exists in a db with ajax call while a condition is not met.

This is my call:

```
 var checkForDoc = false;
            var i = 0;
            do {
                $timeout(function () {
                    $http({
                        url: 'http://localhost:52876/api/Admin/CheckForDoc',
                        method: "POST",
                        async: false,
                        params: { loanID: $scope.loanIdPopup }
                    }).success(function (data, status) {
                        if (data === 'OK') {
                            checkForDoc = true;
                        }
                        else{
                            i++;
                        }

                        if (i == 23) {
                            checkForDoc = true;
                        }
                    }).error(function (data, status) {
                        console.log(data);
                    });
                }, 5000);

            } while (!checkForDoc);

            if (checkForDoc) {
                $uibModalInstance.close();
            }
```

So I would like to check every 5 seconds if the entry exists in the db and if it does set the checkForDoc to true which will close the modal popup. In case, the row does not exist after 2 minutes I'll close the popup as well, but as I said initially once I'll reach the do line in the debugger the browser stops responding and after a while I'm getting this message

[image]

Comment: As a side note I've found it's almost always a good idea to add a "sanity check" variable whenever I do a `while` loop, eg. `while(whatever) { sanityCheck++; if(sanityCheck > 100) debugger; *rest of loop* }`.  This practice can help save you from browser crashes AND pauses things right at the problem point so you can inspect what's going on.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that's Angular's `$http()` method, it doesn't accept an `async` property on its ajax configuration object. Thus, your code is a tight loop firing up a zillion separate HTTP requests until the browser just gives up.

Even if it worked, that approach is a fairly terrible idea. Synchronous HTTP is a bad user experience because the browser basically freezes up while the network operation is in progress. The `$http()` configuration object *does* support a timeout, and that's probably the best approach.

Comment: Hi @Pointy thx, its doing the same thing withouy async equals false. Can you give me some example how can I do what I'm trying to achieve. Thanks a lot

Comment: Also I have breakpoint in the API in this function /CheckForDoc but that function is not reached at all. So, I'm not sure if the do while condition is correctly written. Thanks again

Comment: @Laziale my point is that it's going to do what it's doing whether or not you have `async: false` in there because Angular won't pay any attention to it anyway.

Comment: It's actually irrelevant whether the call is synchronous because the ajax call is inside a timeout. The timeout can never execute because the current function never relinquishes control to permit any queued actions to run.

Comment: @PMV ah, good point! So the infinite loop has redundant protection :)

Answer (score 0):

this checks conditions in the .success and if not met sets up to fire in 5 seconds. (not tested but you get the idea)

```
             var checkForDoc = false;
                    var i = 0;

                    function doCheck() {

                            $http({
                                url: 'http://localhost:52876/api/Admin/CheckForDoc',
                                method: "POST",
                                async: true,
                                params: { loanID: $scope.loanIdPopup }
                            }).success(function (data, status) {
                                if (data === 'OK') {
                                    if (checkForDoc) {
                                        $uibModalInstance.close();
                                    }
                                }
                                else {
                                    i++;

                                    if (i < 23) {
                                        setTimeout(function () { doCheck() }, 5000)
                                    }
                                }
                            }).error(function (data, status) {
                                console.log(data);
                            });


                    }
                    // set first clock
                    setTimeout(function () { doCheck(); }, 5000);
```